# How to remove an Admob ad from the screen when EditText has focus?

Tags: android, focus, admob

I've searched and found that there isn't a way to determine whether or not the soft keyboard has appeared. However, I believe there must be an action called when I click in an EditText field. I want a way to destroy/dispose of an ad when an EditText field has focus.

I have a RelativeLayout and a ScrollView within that. Below the ScrollView is my ad. Basically, I made it so the ad isn't within the ScrollView so it's always showing, yet I DON'T want it to show when the keyboard is up because it is intrusive to the user. I've gotten adView.destroy() to work with onClick on an EditText but I need to click on the EditText an extra time. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't we set the visibilty gone of adMob or it's parent view.

Comment: Yeah, I had to setup an onFocusChangeListener, apply it to my EditText fields, and do the following:

     if(adView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);